# How to fit all the points in geom_sina into the density created by geom_violin?

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot, violin-plot, ggforce

I'd like for the points plotted by `geom_sina` to match the distribution shape by `geom_violin`.

I've tweaked the `scale` and `method` options but the closest I've come to is this:

```
ggplot() + 
          geom_sina(aes(factor(AC_group), y=g_AD, color=factor(AC_group)), alpha=0.4, scale=F, method="counts") + 
          geom_violin(aes(factor(AC_group), y=g_AD), alpha=0.4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First set the `method = density`. This will scale it more or less the same way as the violin plot.  Then set the `maxwidth` parameter so that the points generate by `geom_sina` fall within the violin plots. This will probably vary a bit based on your particular data.  Here is an example with the iris data set:

```
g <- ggplot(iris) + 
  ggforce::geom_sina(aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length, color=Species), alpha=0.4, scale=F, 
                     method="density", 
                     maxwidth = .6) + 
  geom_violin(aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length), alpha=0.4) 
g
```

Which produces:

[image]